# Xcode crashed after closing app in simulator

Tags: ios, crash, xcode8

Using Xcode Version 8.1, Swift 3

I am trying to test my app's data persistence. So I close the app in the simulator by <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (double tapped), and then slide up the app to close it. But the Xcode crashed with "Thread 1: signal SIGKILL".

How do I close app in the simulator and can still open the app in the simulator after I close it.

Comment: Xcode is not crashing. Xcode is showing that your app has terminated due to being force terminated by the user.

Comment: xcode crashed or it just stopped running your app in the debugger?

Comment: According @rmaddy, Xcode just stopped. But is there any way I could open the app again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode is not crashing. Xcode is showing that your app has terminated due to being force terminated by the user. This happens when you force-terminate an app while debugging. This happens in either simulator or with a real device.

Simply tap the "stop" button in the debugger. You can then run the app again like your normally do.

Comment: Is there any way to terminate the app without "stop" the debugger. If I stop the debugger, I can't debugging. @rmaddy

Comment: If you terminate the app, there's nothing left to debug. So there is no problem clicking on "stop" in the debugger.

Comment: I "stop' the debugger, but after I do that, the simulator doesn't allow me reopen the app. Any idea @rmaddy

Comment: How are you trying to reopen the app?

Comment: I press the "continue program execution" button, then tap the app icon on the simulator, then the icon turns grey, and do nothing.

Comment: Personally i do that for applicationWillTerminate(_ application:) ! How can i debug a user close application action without Xcode !